# press a button and open a file in a new window in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, file-io

I have created a JFrame and a put a textfield and the button.in the textfield i have put a name read from a text file.know i want click the button and aopen a knew window in which i want to put the name + other information from the same file.

here is my code:
This is my main frame

```
   package Frontend;

   import Business.ShowDetails;
   import model.*;
   import java.awt.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.io.*;
   import java.util.*;
   import javax.swing.*;

 public class Gui {
  //String file=" ";
  private JFrame frame;
  private JPanel panel1 ;
  private JPanel panel2;
  private JPanel panel;
  private JTextField nume1;
  private JTextField nume2;
  private JTextField nume3;
  private JTextField nume4;
  private JTextField nume5;
  private JButton edit1;
  private JButton edit2;
  private JButton edit3;
  private JButton edit4;
  private JButton edit5;
  private final String file = "Persoane.txt";


public Gui(){
   fereastra();
   readFile(file);
}

public void fereastra(){

    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2,1,7));
    panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,2,1,1));

    nume1 = new JTextField(15);
    nume2 = new JTextField(15);
    nume3 = new JTextField(15);
    nume4 = new JTextField(15);
    nume5 = new JTextField(15);

    edit1 = new JButton("Edit");
    edit2 = new JButton("Edit");
    edit3 = new JButton("Edit");
    edit4 = new JButton("Edit");
    edit5 = new JButton("Edit");

    panel1.add(nume1);
    panel2.add(edit1);
    panel1.add(nume2);
    panel2.add(edit2);
    panel1.add(nume3);
    panel2.add(edit3);
    panel1.add(nume4);
    panel2.add(edit4);
    panel1.add(nume5);
    panel2.add(edit5);

    ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();    
    edit1.addActionListener(handler);                             
    edit2.addActionListener(handler);
    panel.add(panel1);
    panel.add(panel2);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public String readFile(String filename){
    try{
         String line="";
         Persoana p ;
         BufferedWriter bw = null;
         ArrayList<Persoana> listOfPersons;

          //creez o lista de persoane
         listOfPersons = new ArrayList<Persoana>();
         //citesc fisierul Persoane.txt
        FileReader  file1 =new FileReader(filename);
         BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(file1);

        while((line = br1.readLine())!= null){
          //elimin prima linie din fisier

         if(!line.trim().contains("ID")){
         String[] attributes = line.split(";");// separ fiecare linie in tokenuri

            p = new Persoana(); // make a new person
            p.setId(Integer.parseInt(attributes[0]));
            p.setNume(attributes[1]);
            p.setPrenume(attributes[2]);
            p.setDataNasterii(attributes[3]);
            p.setProfesie(attributes[4]);

            listOfPersons.add(p);
         }

      }
         int i = 0;
        while (i < listOfPersons.size()){
            if(i == 0){
                 p = listOfPersons.get(i);
                 nume1.setText(p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume());
                 nume1.getText();
            }
            if(i == 1){
                 p = listOfPersons.get(i);
                 nume2.setText(p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume());
                 nume2.getText();
            }
             if(i == 2){
                 p = listOfPersons.get(i);
                 nume3.setText(p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume());
                 nume3.getText();
            }
             if(i == 3){
                 p = listOfPersons.get(i);
                 nume4.setText(p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume());
                 nume4.getText();
            }
             if(i == 4){
                 p = listOfPersons.get(i);
                 nume5.setText(p.getNume() + " " +p.getPrenume());
                 nume5.getText();
            }

             i++;
         }
         br1.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error opening file.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
   return file;
}

  // inner class for button event handling
    private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (e.getSource() == edit1) {
                            new ShowDetails();

                    }
                    if (e.getSource() == edit2) {
                            new ShowDetails();
                    }
        }
}
}
```

this is my second cclass:

```
  package Business;

  import Frontend.*;
   import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;
  import java.awt.event.*;




  public class ShowDetails extends JFrame{

  Gui gui;


  public ShowDetails(){

    this.gui = gui;
    fereastra();
}

public void fereastra(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    text.setEditable(true);
    text.setText(gui.readFile("Persoane.txt"));
    text.getText();
    panel.add(text);

    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //setLocation(50,50);
setSize(300,200);
setResizable(false);
   // setVisible(true);
    show();
}


}
```

Comment: We're gonna need you to point out the problem that you need help with.

Comment: The question is? How can i use the first method readFile() from the first class(frame) to show what i need in the second class(frame) by pressing the button.

Comment: Looks like your model and your view are tightly intertwined. Just by reading your code, I would have say that you should probably call `pack();` before `setVisible(true);`  (and don't use show() since it's deprecated)

Comment: You also have two statements that don't do anything: `this.gui = gui;` and `text.getText();`

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: If you're using `this.gui = gui` then your constructor should be `public class ShowDetails(GUI gui)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't to create a new `JFrame`, if you want the popup window use `JDialog` with parent of the frame.
2. Don't use `show();`, because this is long time depreciated method, remove that and  un-commented  `// setVisible(true);`
3. Why two `JButtons` make the same things?
4. Why using `FileIO` for passing value or argument from one `Object` to the other?
5. I'd suggest to use `CardLayout` instead of to create a popup window.
6. `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` from `class ShowDetails` will close current JVM instance.
7. Don't extend `JFrame` or `JDialog` or `JWindow`